# Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли качественная альтернатива selenium для Python?

Tags: selenium

Необходимо осуществить парсинг данных с сайтов использующих ajax. Разбираться с запросами нет времени. Хочу имитировать работу через браузер. Нашёл вариант использования Selenium, но он сразу не взлетел. Подскажите есть ли альтернативы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Селениум самый распространённый и используемый вариант. Стоит разобраться с ним. По селениуму много примеров и документации. Много пользователей могут помочь разобраться и решить возникающие проблемы.
А вообще посмотрите на такой вариант [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/)
[информация для пайтон](https://pythonrepo.com/repo/microsoft-playwright-python-python-testing-codebases-and-generating-test-data)

Answer (score 0):

Есть https://github.com/psf/requests-html, который умеет выполнять javascript и который можно использовать вместе с [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Под капотом он использует chromium, скачивает и запускает его автоматически  и не требует вмешательства пользователя.